# Why does UFW seem to slow down wordpress?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, ufw

I have a speedy install of wordpress going on ubuntu 12.04. Everytime i enable the UFW firewall, things can get really slow.

Sometimes fast, sometimes slow, intermittently.

- Logging on through ssh takes an extra 30 seconds, then it's fast.
- Logging into wordpress admin takes an extra minute.

I enabled a `http` rule, is there some other rule i can set that'll still allow http connections and run wordpress scripts really fast?

Comment: It's happening to me at the moment. Just disable the ufw that the wordpress turn fast like a bullet. I don't know how to solve, a friend of mine adviced me to skip the ufw and learn iptables.

Comment: Could you please paste a summary of all your ufw rules (`sudo ufw status verbose`) while UFW is running?  Also, do you run DNS from the same server?

This may also be a question well-suited to serverfault.com (not that it isn't suited to here as well).